# Combining several columns based on matching text in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, qualtrics

I ran a study in Qualtrics with 4 conditions. I'm only including 3 in the example below for ease. The resulting data looks something like this:

```
condition  Q145   Q243   Q34    Q235   Q193   Q234   Q324   Q987   Q88         
condition  How a? How b? How c? How a? How b? How c? How a? How b? How c? 
1          3      5      2
1          5      4      7
1          3      1      4
2                               3      4      7
2                               1      2      8
2                               1      3      9
3                                                     7      6      5
3                                                     8      1      3
3                                                     9      2      2
```

The questions in the 2nd row are longer and more complex in the actual dataset, but they are consistent across conditions. In this sample, I've tried to capture the consistency and the fact that the default variable names (all starting with Q) do not match up.

Ultimately, I would like a dataframe that looks like the following. I would like to consolidate all the responses to a single question into one column per question. (Then I will go in and rename the lengthy questions with more concise variable names and "tidy" the data.)

```
condition  How a? How b? How c? 
1          3      5      2
1          5      4      7
1          3      1      4
2          3      4      7
2          1      2      8
2          1      3      9
3          7      6      5
3          8      1      3
3          9      2      2
```

I'd appreciate any ideas for how to accomplish this.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share your data.

Comment: The data itself is too complicated to use dput(). I've tried creating a reproducible version of the original dataframe but am not sure how to account for the large gaps...what do I since each row has 6 empty columns? I'm trying to use something like the following: x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))

Comment: Please don't use comment section to add data of any sort. You should search for "wide to long r", it's that kind of a problem. My guess is you'll solve things using `tidyr::gather`.

Comment: To clarify, I wasn't trying to add data in a comment. I was trying to ask how I can create a reproducible version of the data, which I would then add to the question, per markus's request.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

file = 'condition,Q145  ,Q243  ,Q34   ,Q235  ,Q193  ,Q234  ,Q324  ,Q987  ,Q88
        condition,How a?,How b?,How c?,How a?,How b?,How c?,How a?,How b?,How c?
        1        ,3     ,5     ,2     ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,
        1        ,5     ,4     ,7     ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,
        1        ,3     ,1     ,4     ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,
        2        ,      ,      ,      ,3     ,4     ,7     ,      ,      ,
        2        ,      ,      ,      ,1     ,2     ,8     ,      ,      ,
        2        ,      ,      ,      ,1     ,3     ,9     ,      ,      ,
        3        ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      , 7    , 6    , 5
        3        ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      , 8    , 1    , 3
        3        ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      ,      , 9    , 2    , 2'

# Read in just the data without the weird header situation
data <- read_csv(file, col_names = FALSE, skip = 2)

# Pull out the questions row and reshape into a dataframe to make the next part easy
questions <- gather(read_csv(file, col_names = FALSE, skip = 1, n_max = 1))

# Generate list of data frames (one df for each question)
split(questions, questions$value) %>%
  # Then coalesce the columns
  map_df(~do.call(coalesce, data[, .x$key]))
```

Gives the following result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 4
  condition `How a?` `How b?` `How c?`
      <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1         1        3        5        2
2         1        5        4        7
3         1        3        1        4
4         2        3        4        7
5         2        1        2        8
6         2        1        3        9
7         3        7        6        5
8         3        8        1        3
9         3        9        2        2
```

Of course, if you intend to move to long format eventually, you might just do something like this:

```
data %>%
  gather(key, answer, -X1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(answer)) %>%
  left_join(questions, by = 'key') %>%
  select(condition = X1, question = value, answer)
```

Resulting in the following:

```
# A tibble: 27 x 3
   condition question answer
       <int> <chr>     <int>
 1         1 How a?        3
 2         1 How a?        5
 3         1 How a?        3
 4         1 How b?        5
 5         1 How b?        4
 6         1 How b?        1
 7         1 How c?        2
 8         1 How c?        7
 9         1 How c?        4
10         2 How a?        3
# ... with 17 more rows
```